# Use the Firebase Admin SDK and Client SDK at the same time in node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am facing an issue in setting up Client SDK in NodeJS.
I have already initialized both SDK in the Node Server using the following code:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const client = require('firebase');

const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://*******.firebaseio.com"
});

client.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "**************",
  authDomain: "***********.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://*********.firebaseio.com",
  storageBucket: "**********.appspot.com"
});

const clientAuth = client.auth();
```

The admin SDK is working fine but when I try to add the Client SDK, it's throwing me the following error.

> client.auth is not a function

I am new to firebase, so confused whether we cannot initialize both the SDK in the same Node Server

**UPDATE**

I have tried with the firebase v4.6.2, its working and it's not showing the error till version v4.7.0. but when I switch to the v4.8.0, the client SDK is throwing me the error. When I tried to initialize the client SDK separately in a node server it's working, so after v4.8.0 is it not recommended to use both client and admin SDK on the same node server?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by initializing both client and (typically server-side) admin SDKs in a single script?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i need the email verification of the client side sdk and also the FCM of the admin sdk, so i was thinking of intialising both on a single node instance and use accordingly.
Please advice if the usage is incorrect

Comment: Can you try with firebase 4.6.2 and see if that works? We use `firebase.auth()` in our [integration tests](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/blob/master/test/integration/auth.spec.ts#L157) (using v4.6.2), and that seems to work fine.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka I am using latest "firebase": "^4.9.0", still facing the issue, can you please give a sample code having both the admin and client SDK initialized together if possible

Comment: My intention was to get you to use an "older" version of the firebase package. I've already linked to a sample code above (see the integration test)

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka I have tried with the firebase 4.6.2, its working and it's not showing error till version 4.7.0. when I switch to the 4.8.0, the client SDK is throwing me the error.
When I tried to initialize the client SDK separately in a node server it's working, so after 4.8.0 is it not recommended to use both client and admin SDK on the same node server ?

Comment: JS SDK has made some structural changes recently, and this may be a regression. Could you file a bug at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka ohk thanks, will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `client.auth is not a function` error was fixed in the [v4.9.1 release](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/releases/tag/firebase%404.9.1) on February 1st. It appears to be dependant only on the client SDK & not related to using the Admin SDK as well.

Your code should work as-is once you update.

Comment: thanks for the info, let me check with the latest version and see if the issue still persist.

Comment: This may have been true at the time, but no longer seems to be the case as of v4.13.1. There is an ongoing issue for this on the [Firebase github repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/752)